# Popup Window to go first or second

Tags: java, android-studio, tic-tac-toe

I'm writing a simple tic tac toe game and after each win or loss, I want the player to chose whether they want to go first or second (be the X or 0). What is the best strategy for getting this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Display an `AlertDialog` for this to have `RadioButton` for 0 and X so its easy and recommended way to give an options to players .

See sample code for your reference:

```
AlertDialog playerDialog;

// Strings to Show In Dialog with Radio Buttons
final CharSequence[] items = {" Zero "," Cross "};

 // Creating and Building the Dialog 
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Select Your Player");
builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
switch(item)
{
case 0:
// Your code when first option selected
break;
case 1:
// Your code when 2nd  option selected
break;
}
playerDialog.dismiss();    
}
});
playerDialog = builder.create();
playerDialog.show();
```